Optimization under constraint that the matrix should be positive definit
Can someone point to me some text book or reference with practical application of how I can do minimization/maximization for the following problem :
$$ min(f(\Sigma)) \text{ s.t } \Sigma  \succ 0 $$
Where $$\Sigma=\begin{bmatrix}
    \sigma_{0}^2 & \sigma_{01} & \sigma_{02} & \sigma_{03} \\
    \sigma_{01} & \sigma^2_{1} & \sigma_{12} & \sigma_{13} \\
    \sigma_{02} & \sigma_{12} & \sigma^2_{2} & \sigma_{23} \\
    \sigma_{03} & \sigma_{13} & \sigma_{23} & \sigma_{3}^2
\end{bmatrix}
\text{ and } f(\Sigma)=\frac{\sigma_{02}+\sigma_{03}+\sigma_{12}+\sigma_{13}}{\sqrt{\sigma_{0}^2+\sigma_{1}^2+2\cdot \sigma_{01}}\sqrt{\sigma_{2}^2+\sigma_{3}^2+2\cdot \sigma_{23}}}$$
On top of that I need to say that the only value that can move are the $\sigma_{03}$, $\sigma_{12}$ $\sigma_{13}$
I think that it's a convex problem and that CVX in python can be used but I'm not sure how to move from here.

The book Convex Optimization by Boyd and Vandenberghe is a good reference to be aware of.

The constraint is a positive definite constraint and not positive semidefinite constraint, so there is a possibility that there is no optimal value as the feasible set is not closed right?
